Relation between eigenvalues of a non self-adjoint operator $K$ and a self-adjoint operator $K^*K$
I have a question about a relation of eigenvalues between operators acting on a Hilbert space $H$. More precisely, I have a compact operator $K\colon H\to H$ where $K$ is not self-adjoint. Now we can define the square of the self-adjoint operator $K^*K$, where $K^*$ is the adjoint of $K$, and we denote this by $S=(K^*K)^{1/2}$. For $S$ we know that it has at most countably many eigenvalues such that $0<\mu_1\leq\mu_2\leq\dots$. Let us denote the eigenvalues of $K$ by $\lambda_n$ (it is a compact operator so it has at most countably many of these)
My question is: Is there a relation between the eigenvalues of $S$ and $K$?

The eigenvalues of $S$ are the singular values of $K$.

@daw Thanks for your comment. Do you think that there is no relation between the eigenvalues themselves? Like the real part of $\lambda_n$ and $\mu_n$ for example?
